# Ruby On Rails - Geocoder - Near with condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, geolocation, rails-geocoder

I'm using GeoCoder in my application. Now I need to search for objects in my database which are close to a position OR have specific attribute set. I would like to perform this action in one database query, because the database is realy huge.

I would like to have something like

```
  Spot.near([lat,long],distance).where("visited = ?",true).
```

The distance and the visited attribute should be combined with an OR, not with an AND.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based off of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9420230/394282) answer, you should be able to do something like:

```
near = Spot.near([lat, long], distance)
visited = Spot.where(visited: true)

near = near.where_values.reduce(:and)
visited = visited.where_values.reduce(:and)

Spot.where(near.or(visited))
```

Comment: Hej Luke,Thanks for your answer. I will give it a try later. I will post if it works...

Comment: My where values were a nested array, so I had to throw in a `.flatten` before `.reduce`. Other than that it works well.

Comment: Oh and I also wanted to keep the `SELECT` values of the original `.near` query, so I did something like `near.unscope(:where).where(where_near.or(where_visited))`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the process of upgrading a Rails application from Rails 4 to Rails 7 and ran into this problem. While I have no doubt Luke's suggestion worked in earlier versions, it doesn't work in Rails 7 (I'm currently running activerecord-7.0.3.1.

In my particular case, I am using the geocoder `near()` method to return results that are within a 20 mile radius of the query, but I also wanted to use OR conditions to return results where the query was similar to the text values in either the `name` or `location` columns from the `items` table in an attempt to return relevant `items` that haven't been assigned latitude and longitude values.

In Rails 4, my solution was:

```
select("items.*").near(q, 20, select: :geo_only).tap do |near_query|
  near_query.where_values.last << sanitize_sql([" OR items.location LIKE ? OR items.name LIKE ?", "%#{q}%", "%#{q}%"])
end
```

In Rails/ActiveRecord 7, the `where_values()` method no longer exists. Searching for an alternate solution led me to this post. I wound up spending a fair amount of time perusing the latest ActiveRecord and Arel code for a solution. Here's what I came up with,

**Rails 7 solution:**

```
t = Item.arel_table
arel_geo_conditions = Item.near(q, 20).where_clause.ast # ast: Abstract Syntax Tree
Item.where(arel_geo_conditions.or(t[:location].matches("%#{q}%").or(t[:name].matches("%#{q}%"))))
```