# How can query the same model twice with different conditions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Kid model that belongs to a Mom and a Dad.

```
class Kid
  belongs_to :mom
  belongs_to :dad 
end

class Mom
  has_many :kids
  has_many :dads, through: :kids
end

class Dad
  has_many :kids
  has_many :moms, through: :kids
end
```

Now what I'm doing is listing a Dad's kids based on when it was created, age and distance from the Mom.

```
def show
  @dad = Dad.find(params[:id])
    near = Mom.near(@user_location, 100, :select => "kids.*") # Geocoder gem
  @kids = @dad.kids.joins(:mom).merge(near).order(age: :asc, created_at: :desc).page(params[:page])
end
```

I have a boolean field on the Mom model called `is_online`. I want this field to make it so results won't be based on the `near` method or distance and the the online moms will be in front. So, the results of the pagination would look like:

```
online kid, 2 years old
online kid, 3 years old
offline kid, 4 years old, 4 miles away
offline kid, 5 years old, 5 miles away
```

My problem is, I don't know how to make my Kid be just one scope so I don't have to make `@online_kids` and `@offline_kids`. I just want to keep it as `@kids`. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's a bit unclear for me. What do you want your `@kids` variable to hold?

Comment: @MarekLipka I want the online kids to be with the offline kids so there's only 1 scope which is `@kids`. I confused the words scope and query, sorry.

Comment: So you have it now (`@kids` holds both `online` kids and `offline` kids). How do you want to improve it?

Comment: Why not just add an additional order condition on the `is_online` field? (make it first)

Comment: I guess you have forgot some `< ActiveRecord::Base` in your class definitions.

Answer (score 2):

So you have to use `order` clause, I guess:

```
@kids = @dad.kids.joins(:mom).merge(mom).order('moms.is_online DESC, kids.age ASC, kids.created_at DESC').page(params[:page])
```

You build your `Mom` query this way, basing on [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15056333/ruby-on-rails-geocoder-near-with-condition):

```
near = Mom.near(@user_location, 100, :select => "kids.*").where(is_online: false).where_values.reduce(:and)
online = Mom.where(is_online: true).where_values.reduce(:and)
mom = Mom.where(near.or(online))
```

Comment: Hmm, i guess you'd need to put the `is_online` as the first column to order by.

Comment: @Magnuss thanks. That's why I wrote I don't remember if I used good order.

Comment: @MarekLipka I actually have to change my question somewhat since I just realized my design flaw. I'm making the `is_online` attribute be apart of the `Mom` instead. So, it will be `kid.mom.is_online` and not `kid.is_online`.

Comment: @user2784630 so you need to order through join table. I edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @MarekLipka Thanks, this solves the problem of ordering the results for online moms to be in front but what about getting them to appear? Geocoder is making it return results for that have addresses only so it can geocode based on distance but I need it to automatically include online moms regardless of distance. Hope I'm making sense.

Comment: @user2784630 Could you update your question and elaborate a bit more on current problem? It's a bit hard to understand.

Comment: @user2784630 if I understood you correctly, my (once again) edited answer should help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create different scope for online and offline, like this:

```
class Kid
  belongs_to :mom
  belongs_to :dad 

 scope :online,  lambda { where(:is_online => true) }
 scope :offline, lambda { where(:is_online => false) }
end
```

Now, You can further filter search results by these scope.

For example

```
 kids = Kid.where(:age > 2)
 kids.online   # these will be online  kids
 kids.offline  # these will be offline kids
```

Comment: I actually have to change my question somewhat since I just realized my design flaw. I'm making the is_online attribute be apart of the Mom instead. So, it will be kid.mom.is_online and not kid.is_online

Comment: In that case, you can shift these scope to Mom class, does this solve your problem, or yours issue is different.

Comment: @saurabh read the question carefully and you will know it doesn't.