# ActiveRecord scope with nested parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Currently, I have a scope defined as following to query all records where the model OR it's child model have been updated:

```
scope :updated_after, ->(time) { 
   joins(:nested_resources).where("resources.updated_at > ? OR nested_resources.updated_at > ?", time, time) 
}
```

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: simplicity is not measurable. so what exactly do you want to know? if you are talking about a nested resource, you could use `touch` to update the parent on save, but does that make it easier? no idea.

Comment: By simpler, I mean without having to write an explicit SQL string in the where clause.

Comment: you could use AREL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976358/activerecord-arel-or-condition