# Rails 4 Syntax - Multiple Conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How would I write this correctly?

```
Request.pending.where(.....)  ## Request.pending = request.state_id in (1..3)
```

where these are the conditions:

```
approver1_id = current_user and state_id = 1
or
approver2_id = current_user and state_id = 2
or
approver3_id = current_user and state_id = 3
```

It would be really nice if I could put these conditions in the model for use in other controllers/views, too, because I will use these conditions quite often throughout the app.

Comment: Perhaps `Request.pending.where(approver1_id: current_user, state_id: 1)`. Or you need all 3 at the time?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the OR in between...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
Request.pending.where(
  '(approver1_id= ? AND state_id= ?) OR
   (approver2_id= ? AND state_id= ?) OR
   (approver3_id= ? AND state_id= ?)',
  current_user.id,
  1,
  current_user.id,
  2,
  current_user.id,
  3
)
```

Edit:
I forgot that you should use colons. And shouldn't it be 'current_user.id'? It is also unclear whether your Request use the three parameters approver1_id - approver3_id or just one approver_id per request.

Edit 2:
Changed query to SQL.

Comment: Hm, both of the above answers ignore the current_user condition - it shows requests meeting state_ids 1-3, but ignores the approver1-3.  I tried it with current_user and current_user.id.

Comment: A REQUEST has three approvers for three states.  I am only pulling pending requests with the scope: `Request.pending = state_id of 1-3, which is: (Pending Approval 1, Pending Approval 2, Pending Approval 3).`  If the Request is Pending Approval 1 and I am Approver 1, the record needs to show in my list - same if I am Approver 2 and the request is Pending Approval 2... etc.  But, if I am Approver 1 and the request is Pending Approval 2, then I don't want to see the record in my list.

Comment: @KatieM current user can be only one at a time right? That's why i'm checking for current_user.id only. Maybe you try to improve your DB schema. Otherwise make your question more specific.

Comment: A current_user can sometimes be a combination of approver 1, 2 and/or 3, so it has to be an OR condition where the state number matches the approver number - I'm not sure how to change the DB schema to fit these criteria, but I welcome suggestions.  Maybe I can put something in the user model that finds my_pending_requests?  That's why I'm here..

Comment: OK, I changed the query to SQL. It is not beautiful but it should work.

Comment: Indeed, that DB schema seems a bit clumsy. Why not define has_many approvers for Request, where an approver-type-id (1,2 or 3) of a User matches the state_id of the Request?

Comment: The messy SQL works with the clumsy DB schema.  :)  Thanks for the suggestion; I'm not sure how to define "match approver number to state number", but I will work on that, because that is what I want it to do...that's why I come here!

Answer (score 8):

To answer the second part of your question about reusing this query, you can just define a class method on `Request` that accepts a user parameter:

```
# usage: Request.pending_approval(current_user)
def self.pending_approval(user)
  pending.where("(approver1_id = :user AND state_id = 1) OR 
                 (approver2_id = :user AND state_id = 2) OR 
                 (approver3_id = :user AND state_id = 3)", 
                user: user)
end
```

If you want to be able to reuse the individual fragments of the query and combine them as needed, see [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13754977/2004045) (Note, the answer linked to is better than the accepted one, IMO).

Answer (score 1):

Well

First get all the state_id & store it in array. and then pass that array in where clause. It is similar to Mysql **IN** query.

Hence your query will be something like:

```
state_id = [1, 2, 3]  
Request.pending.where(:state_id => state_id AND :approved_id => current_user.id)
```

I hope it will fetch you the desired result.

Comment: does rails 4 not accept `Request.pending.where('state_id IN [1,2,3]')` ?

Comment: Request.pending is already defined in the model.  I need the state_id number to match the approver_id number.