# Rails combine multiple activerecord relations

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, activerecord-relation

I want to union multiple active record relation

For example,

```
apple_companies = Company.where("name like ?","%apple%")
banana_companies = Company.where("name like ?","%banana%")
```

I want to combine these two relation.

not merge, merge is
     apple_companies.merge(banana_companies)
=>     Company.where("name like ? and name like ?", "%apple%","%banana%")

I want to
     Company.where("name like ? or name like ?", "%apple%","%banana%")

afterward,

I will code

```
companies = Company.none
company_name_list.each do |name|
    like = "%"+name+"%"
    companies += Company.where("name like ?",like)
end
```

but code which I wrote make companies to array.....

So I cannot order and page to companies... :(

thank you

Answer (score 5):

```
apple_companies = Company.where("name like ?","%apple%")
banana_companies = Company.where("name like ?","%banana%")

apples = apple_companies.where_values.reduce(:and)
bananas = banana_companies.where_values.reduce(:and)

Company.where(apples.or(bananas))
```

See [ActiveRecord Arel OR condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976358/activerecord-arel-or-condition) for more examples.

Answer (score 5):

The best result for this that I've come across is to grab and merge the ids of the two queries and then search for them like this:

```
apple_companies = Company.where("name like ?","%apple%").pluck(:id)
banana_companies = Company.where("name like ?","%banana%").pluck(:id)
ids = apple_companies + banana_companies.uniq
Company.where(id: ids)
```

It's four lines that seems like it should be doable in one but it works.

Comment: There is no need for the uniq, because the database won't return duplicate rows.  But i'm giving this an upvote because this is what i was going to suggest

Comment: Using `ids` instead of pluck works too:
`apple_companies = Company.where("name like ?","%apple%").ids
banana_companies = Company.where("name like ?","%banana%").ids`

Answer (score 2):

In this case you can use any of the other answers. However in more general cases, I strongly recommend using [`any_of`](https://github.com/oelmekki/activerecord_any_of) gem. With this gem you can do:

```
apple_companies = Company.where("name like ?","%apple%")
banana_companies = Company.where("name like ?","%banana%")

Company.where.any_of(apple_companies, banana_companies)
```

There already is a [pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/10891) to add this functionality to future rails releases.

Answer (score 1):

Please try using

```
Company.where('name LIKE ? OR name LIKE ?','%apple%', '%banana%')
```

OR

```
Company.where('name IN (?)', ['%apple%', '%banana%'])
```

According to your code:

```
names = []
company_name_list.each do |name|
    names << "%"+name+"%"
end
```

Then you can do:

```
companies = Company.where('name LIKE ANY(Array[?])', names)
```

Comment: Company Load (1.4ms)  SELECT `companies`.* FROM `companies` WHERE (name LIKE ANY(Array['%코리아%','%한국%']))
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(Array['%코리아%','%한국%']))'

There is an error.

Comment: Company.where('name IN (?)', ['%apple%', '%banana%'])
This is not "like"

Comment: Company.where('name LIKE ? OR name LIKE ?','%apple%', '%banana%')

I can not use that kind of syntax

Comment: This is my mistake. There is no Array datatype in MySql. This syntax is valid in PostrgesSql.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but `Arel` will solve it.

```
Company.where(Company.arel_table[:name].matches_any(["%apple%", "%banana%"]))
```

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
Company.where(name: IN ('%apple%','%banana%'))
```

Comment: This results in a syntax error. You could use `Company.where(name: ['%apple%','%banana%'])`, but it wouldn't do the `like` syntax the OP requested.