# ActiveRecord: Querying a model with a hash joined by "OR" Instead of "AND"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Say I have a hash like so

```
attributes = {"brown" => true, "black" => false, "rocky" => true, "pebbles" => false, "beige" => true, "white" => false, "red" => true, "pink" => "true" }
```

And I have an model `Beach` where I want to query for the properties in the hash

```
Beach.where(attributes)
```

I believe this joins the hash attributes with the `AND` clause `brown is true AND black is false AND rocky = true.`

I need to join the hash attributes with the `OR` condition `brown is true OR black is false OR rocky is true`. Any Ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976358/activerecord-arel-or-condition

Comment: Not sure if that exactly answers my question, I have a "attributes" hash with a variable number of attributes I want to merge with "OR" in the where clause.

Comment: It does not exactly answer your question, so I didn't post it as an answer :) The article I've mentioned provides enough information to solve your problem, unless you are too lazy to try.

Comment: `arel` can do that. I got it to perform similar queries. You need to get an Arel table, assemble an array of conditions and inject them with `:or`. Typing code on a phone is not too handy, sorry.

Comment: I'm not looking to install anything new like `arel`. Is there anyone I can do this with plain Ruby/ Rails?

Comment: @bennett check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5000839/1081668

Comment: The answer extracts the individual attributes. I have about 100 column of attributes so I would prefer not extracting them individually.