# Dynamically appending .or() calls to an active record query based on array elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have a function which runs a Conditional where query using a hash in order to chain conditions with an AND also.

```
hash = {:cond1 => 6, :cond2 => 3, :cond3 => 7}

Object.where(hash)
```

This seems to work fine for me.

The problem is ,if I had an array of those hashes for example:

```
ary = [{:cond1 => 6, :cond2 => 3, :cond3 => 7},{:cond4 => 6, :cond5 => 3, :cond6 => 7},....]
```

How could I dynamically chain every hash after ary[0] as an OR clause to a where query like so:

```
Object.where(ary[0]).or(ary[1]).or(ary[2])....
```

I think I may have to use lambdas or a block but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Comment: This might help, `arel` is somewhat complicated compared to standard AR, but it allows you to do it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976358/activerecord-arel-or-condition

Answer (score 1):

You can use [inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) to build your query:

```
ary[1..-1].inject(Object.where(ary[0]), :or)
```

This form takes all the elements but the first one, and for each they append `.or(ary[i])` to the result, where the initial value is `Object.where(ary[0])`.

Another way of doing the same thing is using a block:

```
ary[1..-1].inject(Object.where(ary[0])) { |query, cond| query.or(cond) }
```