# Combine two active record relation as active record relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two sets of active records

```
users_by_type = User.where(type: 'customer')
```

Class of this is : users_by_type.class => Active Record Relation

```
users_by_tag = User.tagged_with('admin')
```

Class of this is : users_by_tag => ActiveRecord Relation

When I combine both sets like:

```
users = users_by_type + users_by_tag
or
users = users_by_type.merge(users_by_tag)
```

its give result as Array but I want it as Active Record Relation.

Class of users is: Array

Because in array, I am unable to use where clause and group clause.

How can I combine both sets so that I can use where and group clause?

Comment: Add the definition of `User.tagged_with `

Comment: this is method of gem act_as_taggable

Answer (score 3):

What you need is an `#OR` method for active record, unfortunately that isn't implemented yet, but it's already merged in github and will be released with rails 5

Here's the [pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/16052) and [dhh's comment](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/16052#issuecomment-72718557) about when its going to be released

In the mean time you either have the option to use arel, something like [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976358/activerecord-arel-or-condition/9420230)

Or there's the silly bad way of plucking ids of both queries and then creating a third query with those ids.

Comment: Yes, I need as #OR method for active record, Thanks for quick response its help me.