# ActiveRecord, find all records where associated record EITHER does not exist OR exists with nil status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

3 things:
 - Logistic `has_many` RentalRequests `through` Type_Logistic association table. 
 - Logistic does not have to have a RentalRequest to exist (i.e., there's no Type_Logistic association present)
 - RentalRequest has a `status_id` column

I would like to find all the Logistic records where EITHER there are no associated RentalRequests OR the associated RentalRequest has a `status_id` of nil. My current solution is multi-step:

```
assoc_RR_has_nil_status = Logistic.includes(:rental_requests).where(rental_requests: {status_id: nil}).pluck(:id)
no_assoc_RR = Logistic.includes(:rental_requests).where(rental_requests: {id:nil}).pluck(:id)
inc_logistics_ids = assoc_RR_has_nil_status | no_assoc_RR
@Incomplete_logistics = Logistic.find(inc_logistics_ids.sort)
```

But I'm wondering if there's a way to do this in one single `where` or chain of wheres.

Thanks!

EDIT! Updated my code above because the original `merge` represents an AND not an OR.

Comment: Consider adding a `counter_cache` for RentalRequest to Logistic (see [section 4.1.2.3](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference)). Then you can do `Logistic.includes(:rental_requests).where('logistics.rental_requests_count = 0 OR rental_requests.status_id IS NULL')`

Comment: interesting suggestion, have not thought about it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't be afraid to use SQL. It is a great tool!

```
Logistic.
  joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN type_logistics ON type_logistics.logistic_id = logistics.id").
  joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN rental_requests ON type_logistics.rental_request_id = rental_requests.id").
  where("rental_requests.id IS NULL OR rental_requests.status_id IS NULL")
```

If you must avoid SQL:

It is possible to generate the same query as above using just Ruby code (no SQL snippets). For example you could use ARel, such as is suggested in this [SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976358/activerecord-arel-or-condition).

ARel is great for constructing queries at a high level of abstraction. For the majority of cases I've encountered it is much simpler to use SQL snippets than ARel. Choose whichever is best for your use case.

Comment: you're right, I use pure SQL so rarely I never remember it lol. Here though, I get an error that something is wrong with the syntax `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE"`

Comment: also please note I updated my solution a bit. I need whatever solution is better to match the new output. It was due to a misunderstanding on my part of `merge`

Comment: I've updated my answer to correct the joins, assuming that your table names and foreign keys follow rails conventions. Please change the table names and column names as needed.