# How to write an active record query to select one or the other

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to select Users who own cats OR  a fish as pet. there are users in my table who own both but right now I need only one or the other.

`+----+------+------+`

`| id | cats | Fish |`

`+----+------+------+`

`| 1  |    0 |    1 |`

`| 2  |    1 |    0 |`

`| 3  |    1 |    1 |`

`| 4  |    0 |    1 |`

`| 5  |    1 |    0 |`

Edit: This is needed in PSQL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActiveRecord Arel OR condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976358/activerecord-arel-or-condition)

Comment: ans is this: Foo.where('foo= ? OR bar= ?', 'a', 'b'). reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639656/activerecord-or-query

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make a `WHERE X OR Y` with ActiveRecord today is by writing a piece of raw SQL query in a `where` method :

```
User.where("cats > 0 OR Fish > 0")
```

Comment: Thanks. I gave you +1 for answering

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't want to include owners with both fish and cats and you wanted a way to work across all databases, you can just use:

Owner.where("(cats > 0 AND fish = 0) OR (cats = 0 AND fish > 0)")

or

Owner.where("(cats > 0 OR fish > 0) AND (cats = 0 OR fish = 0)")

Comment: Thanks. I gave you +1 for answering.

Comment: Lol, is this a trick, I didn't get my +1.  I'm not overly sensitive or anything, I am just now curious to know where my +1 went.  I felt like a dog who saw the treat in the hand and saw the hand throw the treat, but then it disappeared.  Where did my treat go?  Arrrrrrrrr

Comment: Someone -1 both your comments. I gave you both +1.

Comment: Oh well.  Easy come, easy go.