# Association query based on child attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.2

How can I get all parents that have no children or in case of children, if its 'state' differs from 'approved'?

`Parent.includes(:children).where.not(children: { status: 'approved' })`

```
"SELECT \"parents\".* FROM \"parents\" INNER JOIN \"children\" ON     "children\".\"parent_id\" = \"parents\".\"id\" WHERE \"children\".\"state\" = 'approved'"
```

It returns only parents with children with `status` different from `approved` but ignores parents that has no children

`Parent.includes(:children).where(children: { id: nil })`

```
 "SELECT \"parents\".\"id\" AS t0_r0, \"parents\".\"date\" AS t0_r1, ........, \"parents\".\"slug\" AS t0_r33, \"children\".\"id\" AS t1_r0, \"children\".\"parent_id\" AS t1_r1, \"children\".\"request_state\" AS t1_r8 FROM \"parents\" LEFT OUTER JOIN \"children\" ON \"children\".\"edition_id\" = \"parents\".\"id\" WHERE \"children\".\"id\" IS NULL"
```

It returns only parents with no children

Comment: Which Rails version are you using?

Comment: Rails 4.2.5, added a tag, ty

Comment: Have you checked questions about `or` query, [like this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976358/activerecord-arel-or-condition)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need to join the two conditions together.

Since `includes` only supports hash like condition in `where` clause, so we need to use [`references`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/references) to write the condition in SQL [source](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations)

> Using where like this will only work when you pass it a Hash. For
>   SQL-fragments you need use references to force joined tables

```
Parent.includes(:children).where("children.status <> 'approved' OR children.id IS NULL").references(:children)
```

Give this a shot